# How to indent a block in a beamertemplate?

Tags: beamer, indentation, templates, block

I would like to design a beamer template in which the `block`s are indented, i.e. their left outer margin is increased. How do I do this?

The width of the block can be set using

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}
```

The only solutions I found use  `columns` which will not work here (i.e. within `addtobeamertemplate`). At least I think there should be an easier way?

Minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\setlength{\textwidth}{0.8\textwidth}% effectively increases right outer margin
% command to indent goes here: it would need to be something that I can use in addtobeamertemplate
\begin{block}{}
  Indent me! 
\end{block}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

```
\newlength{\blockleftindent}
\newlength{\blockrightindent}
\setlength\blockleftindent{10ex}
\setlength\blockrightindent{20ex}
\newlength{\blockwidth}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \setlength\blockwidth{\linewidth}
  \addtolength\blockwidth{-\blockleftindent}
  \addtolength\blockwidth{-\blockrightindent}
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \hspace*{\blockleftindent}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,wd=\blockwidth]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \hspace*{\blockleftindent}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,wd=\blockwidth,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```

Instead of using `\hspace` you could set `\leftskip=\blockleftindent` as suggested in the solution by @Herbert.

## Explanation

The problem is that you cannot achieve that using `\addtobeamertemplate`: if you look at how the template is defined in `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty`

```
\defbeamertemplate*{block begin}{default}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
```

you see that if you add code at the beginning, you are acting just *before* a `\par` is issued. So, unless you want to use black magic to have your code swallow the `\par`, you have to copy over the definition and change it according to your needs with `\setbeamertemplate`. Here I achieve the indentation simply by putting some `\hspace` before the two `beamercolorbox`es that contain the title and the contents. Other means to add that horizontal space may be used.

The alternative with `\leftskip` could be implemented using `\addtobeamertemplate` since the new `\leftskip` value would be used later when creating the `beamerboxes`. However to change the indentation on the right you need to modify the `wd` key of the beamer box environment, which requires again to use `\setbeamertemplate`.

Comment: Perhaps add functionality to set the right indent of the box as well...

Comment: @Werner I added right/left indentation. Similar results can be obtained with `\rightskip` and `\leftskip` as suggested by @Herbert

Comment: Actually setting `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \setlength{\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
  \leftskip=10ex
}` works, I might add it as a separate answer

Answer (score 3):

Using `\leftskip` and `\textwidth` one can manipulate the spacing without resorting to redefining the template

```
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{.5\textwidth}% HERE YOU SET THE DESIRED WIDTH OF THE BLOCK
  \leftskip=10ex% HERE YOU SET THE DESIRED LEFT MARGIN
  \addtolength{\textwidth}{-\leftskip}%
}
```

leading to a more concise solution than the one I proposed in the other answer.
Instead of `\setlength` you could also use

```
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-<rightindent>}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me.  The block is still left aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Indent is 0.1 and the new textwidth is 0.9 of the old one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount\leftskip=0.1\textwidth%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,wd=0.9\textwidth]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \leftskip=0.1\textwidth\usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode,wd=0.9\textwidth]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\begin{document}

\frame{%
foo
\begin{block}{}
  Indent me! 
\end{block}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]